# Why is there a 60fps limitation on React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, uikit, frame-rate

On the [Official React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance), it mentions that “A compelling reason for using React Native instead of WebView-based tools is to achieve **60 frames per second** and a native look and feel to your apps,” however many modern iPhones and iPads include ProMotion displays that power up to 120fps and have included this technology for 3+ years.

Is there a *technical* reason that React Native cannot process UI animations at the native frame rate? (Given the UI is theoretically made up of native components, wouldn’t `push` and `present` navigation at some level call the native methods as part of UIKit that would run at the devices’ current frame rate?)

Example Issues from GitHub:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29333
- https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views in React Navigation use native components and the Animated library to deliver 60 FPS animations that are run on the native thread.

Check this out ~
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/2636

This PR adds support for 120 fps on iOS devices. On Android, 120 fps is already supported without any changes.There's nothing to do. Just make sure that your device has 120 fps mode enabled in the general system settings.

Hope this one helps you with your issue.

Comment: This has been merged. Does this mean react native officially supports 120hz?